Pino logger not working when passed to child of child
First of all, I know dependency injection is most like the best thing for this, however this is the situation I am in for the time being.
I have a Pino logger that I pass to a utility function that in turn wants to pass it on once again to another utility function.
It seems that I can get the logger to work in the first util, but not in the second... What is going wrong and how would one get this to work in this instance?
Parent Class
import {magicUtil} from './utils';

class MyClass {
  private logger;
  constructor(logger: pino.BaseLogger) {
    this.logger = logger;
  }

  doSomething() {
    this.logger.info('This is the doSomething function');
    return magicUtil(this.logger, 'some value');
  }
}

Util
const magicUtil = (logger: pino.BaseLogger, value: string): string => {
  logger.info('this is the magicUtil function');
  return behindTheScenes(logger, value);
}

const behindTheScenes = (logger: pino.BaseLogger, value: string): string => {
  logger.info('this is the behindTheScenes function');
  return `something spectacular happened to value {${value}}`;
}

In this scenario, when I hit doSomething() I am seeing in the logs:
> INFO (xx1): This is the doSomething function
> INFO (xx2): this is the magicUtil function

I am not getting the final expected log of > INFO (xx2): this is the behindTheScenes function.
What am I missing here?

Correcting the typo from your code and adding what is required for an MRE, I can't reproduce this with pino@9.4.0.
package.json
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "pino": "^9.4.0"
  }
}

a.js
import pino from "pino";

class MyClass {
  constructor(logger) {
    this.logger = logger;
  }

  doSomething() {
    this.logger.info("This is the doSomething function");
    return magicUtil(this.logger, "some value");
  }
}

const magicUtil = (logger, value) => {
  logger.info("this is the magicUtil function");
  return behindTheScenes(logger, value);
};

const behindTheScenes = (logger, value) => {
  logger.info("this is the behindTheScenes function");
  return `something spectacular happened to value {${value}}`;
};

const logger = pino();

const myClass = new MyClass(logger);
myClass.doSomething();

output
$ node a.js
{"level":30,"time":1728547536704,"pid":67619,"hostname":"Nova.local","msg":"This is the doSomething function"}
{"level":30,"time":1728547536704,"pid":67619,"hostname":"Nova.local","msg":"this is the magicUtil function"}
{"level":30,"time":1728547536704,"pid":67619,"hostname":"Nova.local","msg":"this is the behindTheScenes function"}


Yes, it does seem to work when I've put this into a codesandbox too... Strange that it doesn't seem to be working in my local stack though. I will investigate more
